# Difference between a (credit union) "share certificate" and a (bank) CD?

Tags: certificate-of-deposit, credit-unions, share-certificate, banking

I've seen both Share Certificates and Certificates of Deposit available.   Are they the same thing?  Do they have different names based on whether they are offered at a bank or credit union?  Does one name typically mean a different legal structure or payment structure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CDs are from banks.  Share Certificates are from Credit Unions.  Otherwise they are essentially the same.  For CDs you are paid interest.  For Share Certificates you are paid dividends.  The CDs at a traditional bank are insured by the FDIC.  The Share Certificates are insured by the National Credit Union Administration (NCUA).